# Cannot trim string (bytes) in OCaml 4.05

Tags: string, ocaml

Using this code

```
let _ =
  let buffer = Bytes.create 100 in
  let bytes_read = Unix.read Unix.stdin buffer 0 100 in
  print_endline (String.escaped (String.trim buffer))
```

I end up with

```
asd\n\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
```

when entering the string "asd", meaning the `\n` char is not trimmed from the buffer. Is this because of the different string implementation in later OCaml versions? What's going on here?

I'm using OCaml 4.05.0, ARM CPU (RockPro64), Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `String.trim` does is remove whitespace from the beginning and end of a string. Your string has no whitespace at the beginning (it starts with 'a') and it has no whitespace at the end (it ends with '\0').

One way to proceed is to extract the string that was actually read, something like this:

```
let buffer = Bytes.create 100 in
let bytes_read = Unix.read Unix.stdin buffer 0 100 in
let real_string = String.sub buffer 0 bytes_read in
print_endline (String.escaped (String.trim real_string))
```

Comment: Thanks. Also worth mentioning `input_line`, that someone mentioned on IRC for me. :)